# Numeric operation using string

Tags: php

I have following string.

```
$option = '+';
$value = '100';
```

I want create new value using above parameters.

ex:- `$newValue = 222 + 100;`

How can i do it using above parameters? as following

```
$newValue = 222 $option $value;
```

Comment: *(tip)* ["The Clean Code Talks -- Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$option = '+';
$value = '100';

eval("\$newValue=" . 222 . $option . $value . ';'); 
var_dump($newValue);
```

Comment: This is very dangerous way!

Comment: If you call **eval()** function be sure you have in **$option** and **$value** variables only operators which you want to support and numbers.

Answer (score 10):

```
function operate($a, $b, $opt){
    switch ($opt) {
        case '+':
            $ret = $a + $b;
            break;
        case '-':
            $ret = $a - $b;
            break;
        case '*':
            $ret = $a * $b;
            break;
        case '/':
            $ret = $a / $b;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception('Unsupported operation!');
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

**Edit**

```
$option = '+';
echo operate(222,100,$option);
```

Comment: this is why ur answer is better and my answer is just being lazy :) and assuming user would get it, :) I have edited it a little for you how to call it but +1 for it :)

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1 for the `throw new Exception` :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$oldValue = 222;
switch ($option) {
  case '+':
  $newValue = $oldValue + $value;
  break;
}
```

Comment: `$newValue = $oldValue + $value;`

Answer (score 4):

```
switch($option){
 case '+':
    $newValue =  222 + $value;
  break;

}


echo $newValue;
```

hope it helps