# Simple function in PHP with Calculation

Tags: php

I am making very simple program in PHP . Tryig to addition first ..

But dont know ..

Here is code

```
<?php 
$a=12;
$b=10;
$c="+";

$res=$a."$c".$b;
echo $res;
?>
```

it output 12+10 as it is concecate..

$c is anything.

Any idea how to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numeric operation using string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887761/numeric-operation-using-string)

Comment: Why do you put `$c` into quotes like `"$c"`? Also why do you put the operator into a variable? If you just write it without the string, it should work.

Answer (score 5):

$c is now a string and not a expression "+" is not equal to +.

So:

```
$res=$a + $b;
```

If you would really need your structure you would have to do something evil like using eval() or you could do:

```
$a=12;
$b=10;
$operator='+';

switch($operator) {
  case '+':
    $res=$a + $b;
    break;
  case '-':
    $res=$a - $b;
    break;
}
```

Comment: No i want to use only $c. not +

Comment: @user950276: If you want to learn PHP, learn to use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to do exactly?

If you have the operator as a string, you could try a `switch` statement:

```
<?php 
$a=12;
$b=10;
$c="+";

switch($c) {
  case '+': 
      $res = $a + $b;
      break;

  case '-':
      $res = $a - $b;
      break;
}
var_dump($res);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, also PHP has an `eval(uate)` function:

```
$res = eval($a . $c . $b);
```

Be sure that $a, $b and $c do not stem from form input, as eval can delete and so on.